# PHP MySQL Insert Into query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Anything wrong with this query?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO creditpurchasehistory (usercode, dollar_amount, payment_id, description, age, request_id, currency, time, currency_amount, quantity) VALUES (code360, 6.97, 4565425552154, Buy_Credits_For_Access, 347162, 7bd92f9489acbff04f80484d94c63282_9354, USD, 1376952971, 12.5, 1 )"
```

That is the echoed version of the query. The original sql statement was

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO creditpurchasehistory (" . $Fieldnames . ") VALUES (" . $Fieldvalues . ")");
```

`$Fieldnames` is a variable containing the field names separated by commas and `$Fieldvalues` is for the values. I made sure the field names exists in the table. The problem is it's not inserting records into the table, the table is still empty. There's no error or anything, it just finished processing but no records were added to the table.

Comment: You need to use quotes in some of your VALUES.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` when in production if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Thanks Fred, so quotes on text values and it should be fine?

Comment: You're welcome and yes that should do the trick.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that's absolutely correct. why didn't post it as answer.

Comment: If the OP wants me to, sure @Rahul Yet, I stand at being downvoted (*by a certain someone who will remain nameless; he knows who he is*) if I don't add additional info about the "you know what" stuff. It's a "double-edge sword" lol OP has his/her solution and that's all that counts really.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, got your point but don't forget a few bad/smelly fish can't spoil the entire sea :)

Comment: @Rahul Not a "few", just the "one" lol, but I get what you're saying though; thanks ;-)

Comment: @user3613603 How are you making out, success?! Rahul suggested I put in an answer, it's your choice if you want to close the question and mark as solved.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am getting stuck with string issues as I originally had a code to remove all double quotes and now I actually would need them so I am trying to retain the quotes, of course, getting errors as modifying that small code messed up the rest lol. I will post if your suggestion worked as soon as I get out of this mess, hang on pls. And YES, I have been wondering why there are people doing down votes for no reason.:p

Comment: Oh Yeah, this worked out great! Thanks Fred!

Comment: You're welcome and not a problem. So, would you like me to post an answer using some of my comments, so we can close the question? @user3613603

Comment: Yes sir, definitely :) Also do I need to post another question or can I just ask here, I was wondering why double and integer type fields in my database automatically becomes Primary and unique? These fields will not contain unique values so I might not want it that way.

Comment: Ohh.. now that I don't know. It'd probably be best if you were to ask another question. *Plus*, I rectified the "downvote" part ;-) @user3613603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To close the question and mark as solved)

You need to use quotes in some of your `VALUES`.

Some of the values you presently have are clearly text, so wrap those in quotes.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) when in production mode, which will help tremendously.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```